# Mapping data.table columns to named parameters of a funcion

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function `pva2()` whose input contains, a `data.table`, a couple static parameters, and then a list of column names that correspond to columns in the `data.table`.

```
gazemap <- function (x, y, ez, ...) structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), class = "uneval")

mapping <- gazemap(x=smi_sxl, y=smi_syl, ez=smi_ezl)
samplerate <- 500
screen.resolution <- c(1680, 1050)
screen.dimensions <- c(473.76, 296.1)

pva2 <- function(data, samplerate, screen.resolution, screen.dimensions, mapping) {
  .call <- formals(pva)
  .call <- modifyList(.call, mapping)
  .call$samplerate <- samplerate
  .call$rx <- screen.resolution[1]
  .call$ry <- screen.resolution[2]
  .call$sh <- screen.dimensions[1]
  .call$sw <- screen.dimensions[2]
  data[,eval(as.call(c(quote(pva),.call)))]
}

pva <- function(x, y, samplerate, rx, ry, sw, sh, ez, ex = 0, ey = 0, timestamp = -1, minsac=.02, vt=1000, at=100000, blinks = NULL) {}
```

`pva2()` is essentially a wrapper to `pva()` which has a mix of required and optional parameters. I need a way of mapping the columns in the input `data.table` to the function `pva()`. Right now I am doing this by constructing a call, the mapping is stored in a list (basically took the idea of `aes()` from ggplot). Does anyone have any better ideas? Or ways to make this more efficient?